# Unable to launch iOS app without entering Apple ID password

Tags: ios, apple-id, password

I just encountered a case where launching a pre-installed app in iOS asks for my Apple ID password. If I choose not to the enter the password, the app is *minimized*. Here's what I am encountering.

[image]

I can't enter the password because I don't know the password. My Apple ID password is managed by a password manager. While I was able to get out of the loop by copy/pasting the password over iCloud from another device, this interaction raised a couple questions:

1. What is causing the apps from not launching and asking for password?
2. Why on tapping cancel, the app is minimized?

I was unable to find a reason for this phenomenon. I don't know how to recreate the scenario, but have observed it a few times a while back.

I am running iOS 12.1.2.

Comment: If your AppleId password is in a password manager how did you install the password manager? How did you get the 1password icon onto the iPhone?

Comment: This happened long after I have installed the apps and have been using my iPhone for a long while. That’s the whole point of asking the question in the first place.

Comment: That info that these used to work should be in the question. Also how is an app minimized on a iPhone. Also the top bar is red what are you running to do that - if a VPN might that block things

Comment: @Mark I use VPN full time. I have started using VPN only recently, but have observed this issue previously as well. By app minimizing I mean tapping Cancel button returns me back to the Springboard.

Comment: I also have 1Password.  Are you syncing or saving your 1Password with iCloud?  If so, when you cancel entering your Apple ID it might not be able to access the data file so it closes itself.  Try entering your iCloud credentials in a different app or from Settings and see if that works.